# Emiting event from child's ngOnInit to get data for binding causes ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular

In `ListComponent` some init logic should be done before it could be used. After preparations are done the event is emitted from ngOnInit. AppComponent is listening for the event to give data for binding.

Main component:

```
export class AppComponent {
  someList$: Observable<string[]>;

  // initialized EventEmitter       
  onListInit() {
    this.someList$ = of(['Angular', 'React']);
  }
}
```

Child

```
export class ListComponent  {
  @Input() someList = [];
  @Output() initialized: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

   ngOnInit() {
     // setTimeout(() => this.initialized.emit());     
     this.initialized.emit();
   }   
}
```

That will cause ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError. Generally, I understand why it happens but still surprised why change detection is not run after the event is processed (is emitting and listening are not async operations?).

Any good way to do it without setTimeout, ChangeDetectorRef, etc?

[to play with code - stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwjgh2)

Comment: That happens because parent component is checked first, then child component changes its parent value, then parent component checked again to detect the error wich you receive(only in debug mode). Use setTimout to make changes after event loop ends. It's normal approach in such situation. Event emit executed just intime you call it.